# Elasticsearch's Logstash couchdb_changes Plugin

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

Github's page of CouchDB River Plugin for Elasticsearch says: "Rivers are deprecated and will be removed in the future. Have a look at logstash couchdb changes input."

I understand, if I am not wrong, that I have to use couchdb_changes plugin.
How do I index documents from CouchDB to Elasticsearch using couchdb_changes?
Could this be done in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logstash is not made to work with PHP. If you wanted to use PHP, then you would need to write your own shipper from CouchDB to ES. This would not be trivial to do well.

Furthermore, Logstash is a standalone application that represents a pipeline: an input, a mutator (if desired) called a filter, and an output. In your case, the input would use the [`couchdb_changes` plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-couchdb_changes.html) and the output would use the [`elasticsearch` plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html).

This is a very simple, barebones example from Logstash. Note: Logstash uses Ruby syntax.

```
input {
  couchdb_changes {
    db => "yourdbinfo"
    host => "10.0.0.1"
    # if you have a user/password
    username => nil
    password => nil
  }
}

filter {
  # May not need to change anything
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    protocol => "http"
    host => "10.0.0.2"
    index => "your-index"
    document_type => "your-type"
  }
}
```